# How to prevent param and response read by users via network tab?

Tags: php, browser, server

We know that each request to the server can be seen via network tab, both the param and response in any browser.

How can I disable anyone from checking what are the params sent for the request and the response received?

DO I need to encrypt my response? If yes, client must know how to decrypt it right? SO what's the standard encryption used?

with encryption, paramaters still visible to users. They might contain sensitive data. I can only think of encryption but is there any other way which is widely adopted by developers?

What's the best practice in handling data sent to and from server? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How to prevent param and response read by users via network tab?

You can't.

The browser belongs to the user.

If you don't trust the user with the data, don't send it to the browser.

If you need to associate it with the user, then use a session to do so, but keep the secret data on the server.